# List Sort Using Wrapper Class

Tags: apex, wrapper-class

I created following Wrapperclass to sort quote based on ceratedDate

```
global class QuoteCreateDateSortWrapper implements Comparable {

    public Quote quo;

    //Constructor
    public QuoteCreateDateSortWrapper(Quote qu) {
        quo = qu;
    }

    //Compare the quotes based on CreatedDate
    global Integer compareTo(Object compareTo) {
        //Cast argument to QuoteCreateDateSortWrapper
        QuoteCreateDateSortWrapper compareToQuo = (QuoteCreateDateSortWrapper) compareTO;

        //The return value of 0 indicates that both elements are equal.
        Integer returnValue = 0;
        if(Quo.CreatedDate > compareToQuo.Quo.CreatedDate){
            //Set the return value to positive value.
            returnValue = 1;
        }else if (Quo.CreatedDate < compareToQuo.Quo.CreatedDate) {
            //Set the return value to a negative value.
            returnValue = -1;
        }

        return returnValue;
    }

}
```

I created following quoteList to for different validation.

```
List<Quote> quoteList = new List<Quote>([SELECT Id,IsSyncing,CreatedDate FROM Quote WHERE OpportunityId = :opp.Id]);
```

now I am trying to copy the above quoteList to wrapperclass list, but I am getting error.

```
List<QuoteCreateDateSortWrapper> quoListW = new List<QuoteCreateDateSortWrapper>();
                    quoListW.addALL(quoteList);
```

Could you please help me to understand what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You need to "wrap" each record individually.

```
List<Quote> quoteList = [SELECT Id,IsSyncing,CreatedDate FROM Quote WHERE OpportunityId = :opp.Id]; 
List<QuoteCreateDateSortWrapper> quoListW = new List<QuoteCreateDateSortWrapper>();
for(Quote record: quoteList) {
  quoListW.add(new QuoteCreateDateSortWrapper(record));
}
```